# How to configure hot reload on directory which is being changed by overriding its files?

Tags: webpack, gulp, gulp-watch, nuxt.js, hot-reload

My `Nuxt` project uses hidden `.pages` directory instead of original `pages`. `.pages` is a result of copying files from `pages` directories from root and plugins so that it is read-only. I configured `gulp` to collect pages in `.pages` using `gulp.watch`. The problem is that hot-reload works bad in this case. To fix it I tried to set `watch` option in `nuxt.config.js` to observe `.pages` more strict. It helps but anytime I make changes in `pages` directories it just recompiles the entire app and you can imagine that it's too long.
Is it possible to configure watching changes in `.pages` directory so, that hot-reload will work as usual just like changes were made directly in `.pages`?
Below you can see my `collect-pages` script which copies files from `pages` directories across the app in `.pages` and `gulpfile.js` which watches for changes in `pages` and does `collect-pages` on change.

```
// collectPages.js

const fse = require('fs-extra')
const path = require('path')
const { handleRegionPlugins } = require('../_utils')

const region = process.env.REGION

const sourceDir = path.resolve(__dirname, '../../../pages')
const distDir = path.resolve(__dirname, '../../../.pages')

fse.removeSync(distDir)
fse.copySync(sourceDir, distDir)

if (region) {
  /** Adding region plugins pages. */
  handleRegionPlugins(region, (pluginDir) => {
    const pluginSourceDir = `${pluginDir}/pages`
    if (fse.existsSync(pluginSourceDir)) {
      fse.copySync(pluginSourceDir, distDir)
    }
  })

  /** Adding region pages. */
  const regionSourceDir = path.resolve(
    __dirname,
    `../../../plugins/regions/${region}/pages`
  )
  if (fse.existsSync(regionSourceDir)) {
    fse.copySync(regionSourceDir, distDir)
  }
}



// gulpfile.js

const { exec } = require('child_process')
const path = require('path')
const { watch } = require('gulp')

const region = process.env.REGION

function collectPages(cb) {
  exec('npm run collect-pages')
  cb()
}

function defaultTask(cb) {
  /** Watching for changes in base pages. */
  watch(path.resolve(__dirname, '../../../pages/**/*'), collectPages)

  if (region) {
    /** Watching for changes in region plugins pages. */
    handleRegionPlugins(region, (pluginDir) => {
      watch(`${pluginDir}/pages/**/*`, collectPages)
    })

    /** Watching for changes in region pages. */
    watch(
      path.resolve(__dirname, `../../../plugins/regions/${region}/pages/**/*`),
      collectPages
    )
  }

  cb()
}
```

Comment: Instead of removing the .pages dir completely maybe a tool like `rsync` can help? As far as I understand if you just edit one file in .pages it would not recompile the whole app...